# No fear for nuclear explosion

Tags: situation

On one day,billions of people sees lights from real nuclear explosion, but they don't escape and even have no fear for that, just continue their life as usual, why?

Answer (score 4):

Because:

> The sun is a constant nuclear reaction

Though:

> I don't know whether it qualifies as an *explosion*, per se.

If not:

> Maybe you could be thinking of a solar *flare*?

Comment: I've read somewhere that the amount of heat generated inside the sun per cubic meter of volume is roughly the same as the amount generated by a compost heap. It's just very, very big.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Depending on how you calculate it, it can either be better or worse.

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps (similar to the answer @boboquack gave):

> They are looking at the light from a supernova?

Though:

> I don't know that a *billion* people would be looking at it - nominally they could, since it'd likely look like a star in the sky, but how many people can/do look at stars...?

They would not be scared:

> Because the supernova itself happened a long time ago - the light took until now to reach Earth, but the event itself is long past.

Of course, there are a bunch of other explanations:

> Because they didn't notice that the supernova was different from any other star... because they knew the supernova was far, far away from Earth... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps they

> are watching recorded videos of the atomic bombs dropped on Hiroshima and Nagasaki of Aug.6th / 8th 1945...in their television sets :-)

Comment: I doubt that 'billions of people' watch this every day. A couple of thousand at most probably.

Comment: It is mentioned on one day. Not **every day**.

Comment: It still says 'billions'.